# ODD and EVEN Digits

Tags: c#

i have a code capturing ODD EVEN numbers in a textbox , is there a betterway of doing this in minimal code? or maybe much faster performance? thnks -john :)

```
                string givenamnt = Convert.ToString(txtamount.Amount.Replace(".", ""));
                int glength = givenamnt.Length;
                var regex = new Regex("[1]|[3]|[5]|[7]|[9]");

                string odd = null;
                string even = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < glength; i++)
                {
                var x1 = givenamnt.Substring(i, 1);
                var isOdd = regex.IsMatch(x1);

                if (isOdd)
                {
                odd += x1;
                txtodd1.Text = odd;
                }
                else
                {
                even += x1;
                txteven1.Text = even;
                }
                }
```

Comment: You are the first guy  who using the regex to find odd and even numbers I have ever seen :)

Comment: yes but i dont know if it is fast :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not an elegant solution, but to get the actual even and odd *digits* you can use this:

```
    string str = "230sd85"; // sample string with invalid input for numbers
    var odd = str
            .Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)  
                && Convert.ToInt32(x) % 2 != 0);

    var even = str
             .Where(x => char.IsDigit(x) 
                && Convert.ToInt32(x) % 2 == 0);

    string oddNums = string.Join("", odd); // 35 - the numbers 3 and 5, not 35
    string evenNums = string.Join("", even); // 208 - the numbers 2, 0 and 8
```

Is this what you meant by digits?

Comment: pcnThird - i only type numbers in my textbox, but WOW this logic is good if i type invalid then it will be ignored!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.You can use [Modulus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

```
if( Convert.ToInt32(x1) % 2 == 0 ) //even
else // odd
```

Comment: for (var x = 0; x < amount2.Length; x++)
            {
                if(x%2 == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ODD.toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(EVEN.toString());
                }
            } thanks man it works